# Implementing Live TextWatcher which change the color of inputed-value

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to Implement controller, TextWathcer or what you like to call for EditText which works on-time, live, real-Time. 
Forexample there is EditText which is:

```
                  <EditText
                      android:id="@+id/width" 
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="30dp" 
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                      android:singleLine="true"
                      android:ems="4"
                      android:maxEms="4"
                      android:background="#FFFFFF"  />
```

OK.

The interval is between 100~1000 and if user inset 1 the TextColor is green, after insert second digit like 8 the TextColor is remain green because 18 is less than 1000.
user insert 3rd digit like 3 and TextColor remain green cause 183 is less than 1000.if user insert other digit(any digit) the value exceed the limitation and Textcolor goes red.

what about this problem, interval is between 36~88. the changing of color must be On-Time, Real-Time or Live.

All Best//

Comment: Your idea seems ok (i.e. the `TextWatcher`). do you have a specific problem when you implement it ?

Comment: yes, idono how to write a listener, as i mentioned i need changing color while user insert digits..I've implemented sth but it needs user interaction ex. press a button.